# Perl Telnet Session Handler

Tags: perl, sockets, unix, telnet

I have an application that makes connections to various equipment in our network on demand, performs several commands, parses the output and reports back to the user via AJAX/JSON/Perl.  In Perl, I am using **NET::Telnet** / **::Cisco**, along with the occasional SSH connection via spawning a child process and passing that to **NET::Telnet**.

I am looking to enhance the application by creating a sort of telnet session holder that will maintain connections after they are opened for a set period of time, or until they time out.  The idea is to cut down on the reconnecting to these devices, and allowing other requests to use a telnet session that was created before (provided it's not in use and is still active).

I started writing a perl file using **IO::Socket::UNIX**, and am able to store the connections w/o issue, and basically another file will use the socket created to access or create new connections.  The problem I am having is this: If two requests hit that socket at the same time, which ever one came in first will cause the second one to have to wait for the first to be done processing.

I started experimenting with using **threads**, but if I do that, I can't pass the **NET::Telnet object** back to the original/parent thread.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?  Is there maybe an application that will act as a session holder that I can interface with?

### UPDATE

I used POE per the suggestion from one commenter, and while this does partially what I'm looking for, it does not allow the 'server' to service multiple connections simultaneously.

Scenario:
Two users click 'send' on the front end rather close together.  User A's query reaches the server first, but they are trying to connect to a device that takes a long time to respond.  Thusly, User B will have to wait until User A's connection is established before User B's request is even started.  Essentially

, I need to be able to service simultaneous requests using a connection pool without creating delay for anyone else just because the guy that got there first is trying to connect to that slooooow device..

Below is my code which, if this is how I would do it, will be run in the background.  The prints are for my debugging.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use JSON;
use Net::Telnet;
use IO::Socket::UNIX qw( SOCK_STREAM SOMAXCONN );

my $socketPath = '/tmp/telnetproxy';
unlink($socketPath);

my $listener = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
    Type   => SOCK_STREAM,
    Local  => $socketPath,
    Listen => SOMAXCONN) 
    or die ("Cannot create server socket: $!\n");

my $clientNum = 0;

our $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;
our $conns = {};

print "Server Initiated...\n";

while (1) {

    print " - Inside while loop...\n";

    my $socket = $listener->accept();

    connectToDevice(++ $clientNum, $socket);

}

sub connectToDevice {
    my $connectionNum = shift;
    my $socket = shift;

    print " - Inside 'connectToDevice'\n";

    print " - Connection #$connectionNum started...\n";

    my $input;
    my $connId = 0;
    my (@argsRaw, $args, @argHold);
    my $numOfConnections = keys %$conns;

    my $deviceProperties = {
        ipAddress => undef,
        username  => undef,
        password  => undef,
        method    => 'telnet'
    };

    print " - waiting for input...\n";

    # Receive input for arguments.
    chomp( $input = <$socket> );

    print " - input received...\n";

    ## Turn string into a HASHREF
    $args = from_json($input);

    foreach (keys %$args) {
        print "\t$connectionNum: $_ => $args->{$_}\n";
        if (/^host$/i) { #---- Host IP given ($self->{_hostIp{
            if (verifyIp($args->{$_})) {
                $deviceProperties->{ipAddress} = $args->{$_};
            } else {

            }
        }
         elsif (/^method$/i) { # Ckt type... very important for how we ts
            $deviceProperties->{method} = $args->{$_};
        }
         elsif (/^(username|user|u)$/i) { # username to log in with
            $deviceProperties->{username} = $args->{$_};
        }
         elsif (/^(password|pass|p)$/i) { # password
            $deviceProperties->{password} = $args->{$_};
        }
    }

    print " - Num of connections: $numOfConnections\n";

    if ($numOfConnections > 0) {
        ## Look through existing connections
        ##  1) If we have an available connection, use it
        ##  2) If not, create a new connection.
        print " - Checking existing connections...\n";
        foreach my $connKey ( keys %$conns ) {
            if ($conns->{$connKey}->{host} eq $deviceProperties->{ipAddress} && $conns->{$connKey}->{locked} == 0 && testConnection($connKey)) {
                $connId = $connKey;
                print "\tconnection #$connKey... VALID, using it\n";
                last;
            } else {
                print "\tconnection #$connKey... not valid\n";
            }
        }
    } else {
        print " - No existing connections, creating a new one ...\n";
    }

    if ($connId == 0) {

        $connId = $connectionNum;

        $conns->{$connectionNum} = {
            host   => $deviceProperties->{ipAddress},
            locked => 1
        };

        $conns->{$connectionNum}->{conn} = connectToHost($deviceProperties, "blab_$connectionNum");
        print " - Created a new connection, a suitable existing connection was not found.\n";
    }

    print " - Waiting for command.. ";

    chomp( my $line = <$socket> );

    print "DONE\n";

    my @out = $conns->{$connId}->{conn}->cmd($line);

    print " - Sent '$line' to device\n";

    my $numOfLines = @out;

    print " - $numOfLines lines retrieved\n";

    $conns->{$connId}->{locked} = 0;

    print " - This run done....\n\n";

    return;
}

sub testConnection {
    my $connectionNum = shift;

    print " -- Testing connection $connectionNum:  ";

    my @out = $conns->{$connectionNum}->{conn}->cmd(String => '!', Timeout => 2);

    print "[";
    print @out;
    print "]";

    if (@out > 0) {
        print " ---- Good\n";
        return 1;
    } else {
        delete $conns->{$connectionNum};
        print " ---- No good\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe an asynchronous loop like IO::AIO, POE or similar would be best for this (all on CPAN)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I will check into this and let you know how I make out.

Comment: POE looks a lot like what I need with one exception:  establishing telnet connections to some of our devices sometimes takes several seconds.  It sounds like even utilizing POE, subsequent requests would have to wait for the connection to be established before we can allow other sessions to get their connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved to using POE server architecture, along with spawning sub/child-processes to handle individual connections.  It's probably not the prettiest/best/most efficient way to do what I want, but it gets the job done and has a vary narrow purpose.

Thanks everyone to all their help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use [ResourcePool](http://p3rl.org/ResourcePool) to accomplish this. Just create the number of objects you need in the pool then use get and free to use them and drop them back in the pool.

Comment: A review of ResourcePool indicates it is something like what I need, but really the problem I'm running into is specifically this: If two users send a request to the server close to the same time, the one that came in late has to wait for the other to finish before the server can respond at all.

I am trying to create a server that would be able to answer multiple requests simultaneously, while sharing a pool of connections that may already be open, AND there will be no delay if the guy who got there first is trying to connect to a device that takes a long time to establish connections.

Comment: On the server side, you may want to look at threads to allow it to handle multiple requests at the same time.  The pseudo logic would be - 1. wait for connection. 2. receive connection and start new thread. 3. allow thread to run and let server go back to listening.  Be careful with this though, you want to avoid deadlock conditions and have correct resource management.

Comment: I have come up with a sort of master/slave server concept.  The master server will listen on a dedicated port, check for any sub-servers for the requested host, or start a new server on a new port, and return that port to the client.  The client will then connect to the given port which will proxy the connection to the desired device.  This sub-server will monitor the connection and terminate itself if the connection terminates.  It will also tell the master server it has shut down.  I'll post back if this concept works.